# Change main URL with htaccess in IIS server

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, uri, iis-10

I'm working with laravel 5.6 project on a IIS server.

I would like to change 
`domain.com/` to `domain.com/something` as a main url for my project using htaccess but I cannot find anything.

This is my current .htaccces file

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Any help?

Comment: You have to setup url rewrite rule for this using IIS UrlRewrite extension. If you can update the question with htaccess file contents may be I can help converting it into urlrewrite rule(s)

Comment: I add already my htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the htaccess file contents I have converted the rules in IIS UrlRewrite rules. For applying these rules, create web.config file in your website root directory and paste the following contents. If a file already exists just copy the `rewrite` section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
               <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                 <match url="^$" />
                   <action type="Redirect" url="/subdir" />
               </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Cant' find the rule to rewrite the URI to domain.com/something

Comment: @CarlosDiaz I just converted the htaccess file contents into url rewrite format

Comment: @CarlosDiaz Kindly check the updated answer. I`<rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                 <match url="^$" />
                   <action type="Redirect" url="/subdir" />
               </rule>`